# Prematurely closed "duplicate"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, duplicates, review

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422844/), asking why oceans look blue but rivers don't, was closed as a duplicate of another question, which was answered with a good explanation of why large masses of water, including oceans and swimming pools, look blue.

The "duplicate" does not address the main thrust of the new question, which can be reworded as "if oceans, then why not rivers?".

I think this was closed prematurely.

Comment: Indeed the closing seems premature. I have reopen the question.